# How to mute push notifications?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Cordova FCM plugin in order to push notifications either for Android and iOS.
I want to allow the customer to mute the notifications - just mute, not block them.

But I can't find out how. I know I can send from first place, from the server, without sound - but in such a case - everyone won't receive sound and this is not the aim. I usually send for topics and from the server I cannot determine who configured his client to mute notifications.

Is this possible to set mute from the client's app?
How does WhatsApp handle this (there you can mute notification but not block them totally)?

Comment: On iOS the user can mute their phone using the mute switch or change the notification settings for a particular app in the settings app. If you wanted to manage it from your side you would need to record in your database which users didn't want sound and which did and send different notifications to the two groups.  Generally it is simpler to let the user manage it on their device.

Comment: You mean - if user didn't switch to mute, he will be subscribed to topic X and if he did switch to mute, he will be subscribed to X-Muted (and unsubscribed from X, of course). Then from my server I anyway emit either for X and for X-Muted.

Comment: Yes, you could do that, but as I said I wouldn't. I would just let the user control it through their device settings.

Answer (score -1):

For iOS,
When requesing for user Permmission we pass the array of required values

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current() 
.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { granted, _ in
  print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
}
```

From the above, just remove `.sound`from options array.